# Displaying each entry of PHP array on a new line in Javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a simple query to select some information from the database:

```
  $dep_qry = "select product_name, sum(theoretical_stock_level) as opening_stock, sum(quantity_scanned) as closing_stock, department_description, stock_item_code, custom_1 AS size, IFNULL(unit_cost_price, 0.00) AS cost_price from stocktake_products where stocktake_id = '{$stocktake_id}' AND is_deli = 0 
                         group by product_name, department_description
                         order by department_description ASC;";

    $dep_res = db::c()->query($dep_qry);
```

I then have the following code to put products with a cost price of 0.00 into an array. I then check the number of elements in the array. If the array has some information in it, I want to display an alert for the user to tell him which items have a cost price of 0. The following code works, but I am wondering if its possible to display each entry from the array on a separate line in the alert box? Just to make it more user friendly.

```
while ($row1 = $dep_res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $cost_price = number_format($row1['cost_price'],2);
        $pname = $row1['product_name'];
        if ($cost_price == 0.00)
        {
            $products[$i] = $pname;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $numOfNoCosts = count($products);
    if ($numOfNoCosts > 0)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('".json_encode($products)."') </script>";
    }
```

If there is a better way of doing this, I am more than happy to take on suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Try this to show like array values on each line

```
alert(arrayname.join("\n"));
```

> Try this to show like an array:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(your_array));
```

first get a js variable ready  with the php array value .
**Like this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = <?php echo json_encode($Your_array); ?>;
</script>
```

> **A full Tried and tested example below**

```
<?php $phpArray = array(
          0 => "Mon", 
          1 => "Tue",  
          2 => "Wed", 
          3 => "Thu",
          4 => "Fri", 
          5 => "Sat",
          6 => "Sun",

    )
?>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;

   alert(jArray.join("\n"));

 </script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, unless I am doing something wrong.. 
`echo "<script> alert(JSON.stringify(" . ($products) . ")) </script>";` gives me an alert with "undefined"

Comment: checkout my answer again for that

Comment: @user3468334 :did you get anythng ?

Comment: Still no luck. If I comment out the obj.join bit, it shows the array in alert box but as one string, not in new lines. This is what I have:
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var obj = <?php echo json_encode($products); ?>
   alert(obj.join("\n"));
   alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
  </script>`

Comment: @user3468334 no way ! i tried the above example it worked for me . please use as i have used ..and remove extra codes like `language="javascript"`

Comment: Yea i tried that example and it worked as well, but not with my data. Are arrays possibly generated differently when getting data from a database? However, this here seemed to kind of work for me:
`var obj = new Array('<?php echo json_encode($products); ?>');
   //alert(obj.join(","));
   alert(obj);`
Its creating new lines, I just need to get rid of unwanted characters!

Comment: what kind of array you have ?? can print your array here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100969/discussion-between-user3468334-and-yo-yo).